# Blackberry: not able to modify the PhoneScreen

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to display custom image and text on PhoneScreen every time an outgoing call happens. I have implemented the PhoneListener interface and tried the following code:

```
    PhoneScreen phoneScreen = new PhoneScreen(callId, app);
    phoneScreen.deleteAll(); // Empty the default PhoneScreen

    phoneScreen.setScreenBackground(0xFF0000);
    phoneScreen.setScreenBackground(0x00FF00);

    BitmapField bmf = new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("img.png"), Field.FIELD_TOP);
    LabelField labelField = new LabelField("Location");

    PhoneScreenVerticalManager psvm = new PhoneScreenVerticalManager();
    psvm.add(bmf);
    psvm.add(labelField);

    phoneScreen.add(psvm);
    phoneScreen.sendDataToScreen();
```

The program crashes because of second line where I try to empty the default PhoneScreen. If I comment that line out then it displays the image at the bottom portion of the PhoneScreen while retaining every other fields from the default PhoneScreen.

I want to delete all the fields from default PhoneScreen and add custom fields. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: add a try catch around phoneScreen.deleteAll() and log out the exception

Comment: "Manager is empty." and phoneScreen.getFieldCount() is returning 0. Just curious, how can the default PhoneScreen be empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hackish solution: Inside the PhoneListener implementation, get the currently active screen and use it as the PhoneScreen. And then empty the screen so that you can add your own fields.

Something like:

```
    Screen phoneScreen = UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen();
    phoneScreen.deleteAll();
    // Add your own fields to phoneScreen now
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the call to `phoneScreen.deleteAll()`.

When the aforementioned line is executed, a `RuntimeException` exception is thrown with "Manager is empty." message.

If you are using BlackBerry API version 6.0 and up consider using `ScreenModel#getPhoneScreen()` instead of `PhoneScreen()` as the later is deprecated. Check [this development guide](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17953/Display_content_on_a_phone_screen_1232117_11.jsp) for more information.

**Edit:** IMHO it is not possible to completely customize the PhoneScreen and the default "*fields*" (not sure that they are even fields) such as picture, phone number and etc, will always appear before the fields that were added programmatically.

Comment: In fact, I am using ScreenModel#getPhoneScreen(). But I have pasted only the code of PhoneScreen modification here.